# Pronoun - The other / The person

Tags: pronouns

Here's a situation.

There's certainly a time when one(A)of the two people(A,B) has come to like the other(B) more than (B) does.

How can I choose the word meaning what I'd like to mean here.

> 1. There's certainly a time when one of the two people has come to like the other more than the person does.
> 2. There's certainly a time when one of the two people has come to like the other more than the other does.

Which one is right?

Comment: "... to like the other (B) more than (B) does" Has B come to feel self-loathing?

Answer (score 1):

The best way may be:

> There's certainly a time when one of the two people has come to like the other more than the second person likes the first.

But I don't know of a true way to do this gracefully in English. It helps to have names:

> There's certainly a time when Alan has come to like Beth more than Beth likes Alan.

If the two people command different pronouns, it can be said as:

> There's certainly a time when she has come to like him more than he likes her.

But if they use the same pronoun, you wind up having to say:

> There's certainly a time when he, Alan, has come to like him, Bob, more than Bob likes Alan.

Or else you could change the wording:

> There's certainly a time when one of them has come to like the other more than is reciprocated.

"Requited" may be used instead of "reciprocated" if you want to to imply a romantic type of love or liking.

Answer (score 0):

The 'functional' (for want of a better term) part of your sentence has a predicate (*like*) that takes two arguments (*one of the two people* and *the other*), whereas the closing part only explicitly provides one (either *the person* or *the other*).

This leaves hanging who the second - unmentioned - person should be. The context suggests that if B is mentioned, the unmentioned person should be A (A likes B more than B likes A). But the sentence would also make sense if the unmentioned person was also B - though the message conveyed would be different (A likes B more than B likes B).

For clarity, consider including both parties both times:

- there's certainly a time when one of the two people has come to like the other more than the other likes the first.